# Put enum in tuple and return tuple from C++ function

Tags: c++, enums

How do we pass an enum in a tuple that is returned by a function? I'm trying the following and it compiles but is this the proper way of doing this?:

Code in header (.h file):

```
enum mode_en { 
    zero = 0, 
    one = 1, 
    two = 2
};
typedef std::tuple<int,int,int, mode_en> mode_tuple;
```

Code in main (.cpp file)

```
mode_tuple func(int val_in) {
    mode_tuple ret_tup;
    int a = 0; int b = 0; int c = 0;
    enum mode_en mode_var = zero;
    mode_var = two;
    ret_tup = make_tuple(a, b, c, mode_var);
    return ret_tup; 
}
```

Comment: I’d suggest using a class or struct to give the values names

Comment: Agree with the class/struct instead of the tuple. Also, `enum class` have been the better enums for quite some time, as they follow the proper scoping rules. Other than that, why would putting an `enum` into a tuple be any different from putting anything else into a tuple? Still, note that you have to be careful with make_tuple to pass in exactly the types you want, or else you won't be getting your desired tuple type. If you construct a mode_tuple directly, you'll get errors when you make mistakes.

Comment: It is correct (as in, it doesn't have any UB and will do what you expect), but it's a very roundabout way to write code. `func` could be simply `return std::make_tuple(0, 0, 0, two);`.

Comment: If you want help improving working code, you should post that complete working code on [CodeReview.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  If you do decide to do so, please delete the question here.

Comment: You never use the input parameter so your entire function can be boiled down to `mode_tuple func() { return {0, 0, 0, two}; }`

Comment: Thank for the suggestions. Sorry I didnt put the entire code in (it was just too verbose) I just wanted to show the way the enum is used.